# Oracle 19c & 12c Create Index Parallel Hint

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, oracle12c, hint, oracle19c

When creating an index the behavior of the `PARALLEL` hint does not seem to operate as expected in both 19c and 12c.

In all 19c cases the hint was `Unused`, but in two of the cases the note actually says `automatic DOP` was used and in those cases it actually processed in parallel.

```
Hint                       DOP  NOTE
-------------------------  ---  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*+ PARALLEL (16) */         1
/*+ PARALLEL (4) */          1
/*+ PARALLEL */             16  automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 16 because of degree limit
/*+ PARALLEL (AUTO) */      16  automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 16 because of degree limit
/*+ PARALLEL (DEFAULT) */    1
/*+ PARALLEL (MANUAL) */     1
```

From Oracle 19c VLDB and Partitioning Guide - Controlling Automatic Degree of Parallelism:

> "MANUAL This setting disables Auto DOP,...With the default setting of
> MANUAL for PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY, the system only uses parallel
> execution when a DOP has been explicitly set on an object or if a
> parallel hint is specified in the SQL statement. The DOP used is
> exactly what was specified."

The DOP was not explicitly set on the table for which this index was created.

Using Oracle 19c with the following initialization parameters.

```sql
set serveroutput on;
show parameters parallel;
---------------------------------------------------
awr_pdb_max_parallel_slaves          integer  10
containers_parallel_degree           integer  65535
fast_start_parallel_rollback         string   LOW
max_datapump_parallel_per_job        string   50
optimizer_ignore_parallel_hints      boolean  FALSE
parallel_adaptive_multi_user         boolean  FALSE
parallel_degree_limit                string   CPU
parallel_degree_policy               string   MANUAL
parallel_execution_message_size      integer  16384
parallel_force_local                 boolean  FALSE
parallel_instance_group              string  
parallel_max_servers                 integer  320
parallel_min_degree                  string   1
parallel_min_percent                 integer  0
parallel_min_servers                 integer  32
parallel_min_time_threshold          string   AUTO
parallel_servers_target              integer  128
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer  2
recovery_parallelism                 integer  0
...
show parameters cpu_count;
show parameters parallel_threads_per_cpu;
---------------------------------------------------
cpu_count                            integer  8
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer  2
```

The index had the following form:

```sql
CREATE /*+ [PARALLEL HINT] */ INDEX OWN.IX ON
OWN.T (some_char, some_number, some_date1, some_date2)
LOCAL NOLOGGING TABLESPACE INDX COMPRESS
```

My session was the only active session and the results were repeatable indicating system load was not a factor. I have explain plans if needed, but this post is long enough as it is.

I attempted a similar task in Oracle 12c (but the index wasn't local and the underlying table wasn't partitioned) with the following results and initialization parameters.

```
Hint                       DOP   Note
-------------------------  ----- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*+ PARALLEL (16) */       16/32 Degree of Parallelism is 16 because of hint
/*+ PARALLEL (4) */          4/8 Degree of Parallelism is 4 because of hint
/*+ PARALLEL */              2/4 automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 2
/*+ PARALLEL (AUTO) */         1 automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
/*+ PARALLEL (DEFAULT) */      1
/*+ PARALLEL (MANUAL) */       1
```

Using Oracle 12c with the following initialization parameters.

```sql
show parameters parallel;
------------------------------------------------------
fast_start_parallel_rollback         string   LOW
parallel_adaptive_multi_user         boolean  TRUE
parallel_automatic_tuning            boolean  FALSE
parallel_degree_level                integer  100
parallel_degree_limit                string   CPU
parallel_degree_policy               string   MANUAL
parallel_execution_message_size      integer  16384
parallel_force_local                 boolean  FALSE
parallel_instance_group              string  
parallel_io_cap_enabled              boolean  FALSE
parallel_max_servers                 integer  320
parallel_min_percent                 integer  0
parallel_min_servers                 integer  32
parallel_min_time_threshold          string   AUTO
parallel_server                      boolean  FALSE
parallel_server_instances            integer  1
parallel_servers_target              integer  128
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer  2
recovery_parallelism                 integer  0
...
show parameters cpu_count;
show parameters parallel_threads_per_cpu;
------------------------------------------------------
cpu_count                            integer  8
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer  2
```

**In 19c:**

1. Why was DOP 1 for the parallel hints with `/*+ PARALLEL (16) */`, `/*+ PARALLEL (4) */`, and `/*+ PARALLEL (DEFAULT) */` cases listed above?  Expected 16, 4, and  16 (=8*2), respectively.
2. For the two cases when the DOP was 16, why does the explain plan say the hint was `Unused` when auto DOP did calculate a DOP > 1?

**In 12c**

3. Why was DOP 1 for the parallel hints with `/*+ PARALLEL (DEFAULT) */`?  Expected 16 (=8*2).

**19c vs. 12c**

4. Why does 19c not produce double the DOP of parallel execution servers like is done in 12c? (In 12c, when auto DOP is 4 we get 8 parallel executions servers, when DOP is 16 we get 32, ..., but this does not occur in 19c.)

Comment: Well, as per the documentation (e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D316D545-89E2-4D54-977F-FC97815CD62E) ) the DDL statements don't take hints. For a create index use the parallel clause to specify the DOP. Try that and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c introduced a hint for parallel dml, **ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML** ,
which you can use directly inside the dml sql statement.

/*+ parallel(16) enable_parallel_dml */